# Does anybody know how to run parallel a Python application?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I would like to use Python for my project but I need to distribute the computation on a set of resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with pyCOMPSs, which is the python version of COMP superscalar.
 More info [here](http://compss.bsc.es)

With this programming model you define which methods are candidate to be executed remotely defining the direction of the method parameters (IN OUT or INOUT). Then the main code is programmed in a sequential fashion and the runtime analyses dependencies between these methods detecting which can be executed in parallel. The runtime also spawn the exectution transparently to the remote hosts and do all data transfers.